# python replace json list values without knowing the keys

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, list

I have this code snippet:

```py
data = {
    "links": [
        {"key_name_not_known": "replace_by_first_value_in_list"},
        {"key_name_not_known": "replace_by_second_value_in_list"},
    ]
}

list = ["hello1", "hello2"]
```

Here I want to replace both values "hello" in `data["links"]` ["keys"]? **without knowing the key value** by the two values in the list, in the right order.

A goal output would be:

```py
data = {
    "links": [
        {"key_name_not_known": "hello1"},
        {"key_name_not_known": "hello2"},
    ]
}
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for index, obj in enumerate(data['links']):
    for key,val in obj.items():
        if len(list) > index:
            data['links'][index][key] = list[index]
```